# Run .BAT via wine cmd

Tags: wine

I tried to run .bat file, but got unknown error:

```
$ wine cmd
CMD Version 1.4

Z:\home\setevoy\Temp\zork1>start ZORK1.BAT
fixme:exec:SHELL_execute flags ignored: 0x00000100

Z:\home\setevoy\Temp\zork1>winevdm: Cannot start DOS application Z:\home\setevoy    \Temp\zork1\nnansi.com
     because the DOS memory range is unavailable.
     Try running this application with DOSBox.
winevdm: Cannot start DOS application Z:\home\setevoy\Temp\zork1\_zork1.com
     because the DOS memory range is unavailable.
```

Can somebody please explain me - what I'm doing wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This dosen't exactly answer your question, but may help you accomplish your goal. If you want to run the old infocom games, you don't need wine at all. You can just install the infocom interpreter `frotz` from either the Ubuntu Software Center or `sudo apt-get install frotz`. You can then run it from the command line with `frotz /PATH-TO-FILE/zork1.dat`. Note that you are not pointing to the batch file, the data file is all you need.